# Question about the proof of: If $m \lt n \Rightarrow f : S^m \rightarrow S^n$ is nullhomotopic.

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, homotopy-theory

[image]

I don't understand the red-underlined sentence.  What are they saying is contractible?  Are they saying $\text{im}|\phi|$ is contractible or $|L| - \{\text{point}\}$ is contractible?  And how do either of these being contractible imply that $|\phi|$ is nullhomotopic?

Comment: $|L| - \{ \text{point} \}$ is contractible -- a sphere minus a point. A map into a contractible space is nullhomotopic, just compose it with the homotopy which shrinks the space into a point.

Comment: How is $|L|$ a sphere?  It's defined in the proof as an $n$-skeleton of an $(n+1)$-simplex.

Comment: the $n-$ skeleton of an $(n+1)$ simplex is, basically, a sphere (homotopy wise)

Comment: Actually the $n$-skeleton of an $n+1$ simpliex is a sphere homeomorphism  wise.

Comment: How is an $n$-skeleton of an $n+1$ simplex homeomorphic to a sphere?  What would be the homeomorphism?

Answer (score 0):

They say that $|L|-$ point is contractible. This is equivalent to saying that there is a continuous map $H:[0,1]\times |L|-point\rightarrow |L|-point$ such that $H(0,x)=x, H(1,x)=p$. You can define $\phi_t(x)=H(t,\phi(x))$ which is an homotopy between a constant map and $\phi$.

Comment: I don't understand, how does a homotopy between $\phi : \text{Sd}^q \rightarrow L$ and a constant map $\subseteq L$ show that $H$ is a homotopy between $x$ and $p$?

Answer (score 0):

$|\varphi|$ is not surjective, so it misses at least one point of $|L|$.  Call that point “point”.  The image is contained in $|L|$ with that point deleted.  That space ($L'=L \setminus \left\{\text{point}\right\}$, not $L$ itself) is contractible.  Contractible means there is a point $p \in L'$ and homotopy $H:[0,1] \times L' \to L'$, such that $H_1$ is the constant map $L' \to \left\{p\right\}$.  The map $\tilde H(t,x) = H(t,|\varphi|(x))$ is a homotopy between $|\varphi|$ and a constant map.

You seem to have some very specific questions like: why is the $m$-skeleton of an $(m+1)$-simplex, with a point deleted, contractible?  That may already be an exercise in the book you're reading.  Whether or not it is, it might be a good idea to try to prove that, and ask a different question if you run into trouble.

Comment: I see that contractible means the identity is homotopic to a constant map, but I don't understand what you're saying the homotopy is here.  You're saying the homotopy $H(x, t) : L' \times I \rightarrow L'$ such that $H(x,0) = x \subset L'$ and $H(x,1) = x_0 \subset L'$ is a homotopy between $|\phi| : |K| \rightarrow |L|$ and a constant map in $|L|$?